# Truck ELD application

Tags: application

I know this is probably stupid but is there a program for Linux that can do what is needed for a truck ELD unit or must I buy a tablet or chrome book to use android if I go back to driving?

Comment: Since the Electronic Logging Device mandate insists that it be "tamper proof", in addition to recording engine/fuel statistics, Linux seems a poor match.

Comment: But android info can be hacked and most ELD apps require permanent phone or internet connection to keep on a cloud account. I mean, anything can be hacked by someone but it is supposed to be like security logs where even changes are noted and nothing can be simply erased